# Application insight not receiving Nlog for hosted service

Tags: azure-application-insights, nlog, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I try everything I can think of but I must miss something.
I have a hostedService project in netcoreapp3.1

I referenced the following

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" Version="2.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.10" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.15" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.7.4" />
```

my appsetting is as follow

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "WorkerServiceTestLog": "Debug"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "XXX"
  }
}
```

The nlog config look like that

```
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget" >
    </target>
    <target type="Console" name="consolelog"/>
    <target type="Debugger" name="debuglog" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debuglog" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="consolelog" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="aiTarget" />
  </rules>
```

I build the host like that

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddNLog(config);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                });
```

The worker simply test the logs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly NLog.ILogger _nlogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Microsoft Logging:Error");
                _logger.LogInformation("Microsoft Logging:Information");
                _nlogger.Error("NLOG:Error");
                _nlogger.Info("NLOG:Information");
                await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have all log information in the console and debugger as excepted
[image]

But only the log from Microsoft extension is going in application insight
[image]

What am I missing there?

Comment: You currently have to enable `EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup` for NLog. See also: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2070#issuecomment-733227455

Comment: Yes `EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup` would do the job, but the post is about using WorkerService package, which do not have `EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup` option. Only option (for worker service) is to manually setup TelemetryConfiguration.Active by hand.

Answer (score 0):

#### Follow the workaround to fix the issue:

#### Startup.cs

```cs
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation(
                "Configuring for {Environment} environment",
                env.EnvironmentName);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

#### Program.cs

```cs
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Setting up the Nlog
            var logger = LogManager.Setup()
                         .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()
                         .GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("Nlog Log: init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(exception, " Nlog Log:Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
            //Configuring the Nlog
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog()
        //Calling the Host Services (Worker) 
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
    }
```

Here is my **worker.cs**

```cs
private readonly NLog.ILogger _nlogger = LogManager.Setup()
                         .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()
                         .GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Microsoft Logging:Error Iteration:" + i);
                _logger.LogInformation("Microsoft Logging:Information Iteration:" + i);
                _nlogger.Error("NLOG:Error Iteration:"+i);
                _nlogger.Info("NLOG:Information Iteration:" + i);
                await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
```

#### Result in Application Insights

[image]

### Updated Answer:

Here you can see the Application Insights connection string get from **secrect.json**

[image]

Comment: `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);` -- This method takes instrumentation key, not connection string. Not sure how it worked.. Maybe you actually passed just instrumentation key?

Comment: It takes connection string only from configuration

Comment: There is no AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry method which takes connection string.  See https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/main/NETCORE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/ApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs#L47

Comment: Please check the updated answer. 'services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);' it will the connection String value from secrets.json.

Comment: It still passes connection string to AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry, which is incorrect. AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry takes instrumentation key, not connection string.

Comment: **Connection String** comes with **Instrumentation Key** and **Ingestion Endpoint**. Check [here](https://i.imgur.com/bkygvor.png)

Comment: ConnectionString has instrumentkey, endpoints etc, but the services.AddApplicationInsights() method does not know how to parse ConnectionString. Passing connectionstring to AddApplicationInsights() is incorrect.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/91065 Issue opened at Azure doc which was stating this incorrectly